# Finding Tags And Text In BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I'm having some trouble formulating a `findAll` query for BeautifulSoup that'll do what I want. Previously, I was using `findAll` to extract only the text from some html, essentially stripping away all the tags. For example, if I had:

```
<b>Cows</b> are being abducted by aliens according to the
<a href="www.washingtonpost.com>Washington Post</a>.
```

It would be reduced to:

```
Cows are being abducted by aliens according to the Washington Post.
```

I would do this by using `''.join(html.findAll(text=True))`. This was working great, until I decided I would like to keep only the `<a>` tags, but strip the rest of the tags away. So, given the initial example, I would end up with this:

```
Cows are being abducted by aliens according to the
<a href="www.washingtonpost.com>Washington Post</a>.
```

I initially thought that the following would do the trick:

```
''.join(html.findAll({'a':True}, text=True))
```

However, this doesn't work, since the `text=True` seems to indicate that it will only find text. What I'm in need of is some OR option - I would like to find text OR `<a>` tags. It's important that the tags stay around the text they are tagging - I can't have the tags or text appearing out of order.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note: The [BeautifulSoup.findAll](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html#The%20basic%20find%20method%3a%20findAll%28name,%20attrs,%20recursive,%20text,%20limit,%20%2a%2akwargs%29) is a search API. The first named argument of `findAll` which is `name` can be used to **restrict the search to a given set of tags**. With just a single `findAll` it is not possible to select all text between tags and at the same time select the text and tag for `<a>`. So I came up with the below solution.

This solution depends on `BeautifulSoup.Tag` being imported.

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup, Tag

soup = BeautifulSoup('<b>Cows</b> are being abducted by aliens according to the <a href="www.washingtonpost.com>Washington Post</a>.')
parsed_soup = ''
```

We navigate the parse tree like a list with the `contents` method. We extract text only when it's a tag and when the tag is not `<a>`. Otherwise we get the entire string with tag included. This uses [navigating the parse tree API](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html#Navigating%20the%20Parse%20Tree).

```
for item in soup.contents:
    if type(item) is Tag and u'a' != item.name:
        parsed_soup += ''.join(item.findAll(text = True))
    else:
        parsed_soup += unicode(item)
```

**The order of the text is preserved**.

```
 >>> print parsed_soup
 u'Cows are being abducted by aliens according to the <a href=\'"www.washingtonpost.com\'>Washington Post</a>.'
```

Comment: Thanks much! I wasn't very familiar with navigating the parse tree aside from using the `findAll` method.